# Time-series model selection

Tags: time-series, arima

I have time-series data that shows the occurrence time of a specific event.
I have looked at ACF and PACF plots and tried to understand if it can be modeled using ARIMA...
The ACF plot gradually decreases and at lag 5 it is below the threshold but after lag 6-7 it again starts to increase. So, can we say AR(5) model is appropriate choice?
The differenced series shows a sharp decrease for ACF plot. Does it show that it is more appropriate for AR model?

[image: time-series data]
[image: ACF plot]
[image: PACF plot]
[image: Differenced series ACF]
[image: Differenced series PACF]

Comment: You should start by plotting the series itself. What does that look like?

Comment: @ColorStatistics I have added the plot of the series itself.

Comment: Is there a structural shift around 140 (in both mean and variance) or is there a downward trend throughout? What makes sense for your variable? Neither the mean nor the variance look constant. You may need to transform your series so that your task becomes one of forecasting a Stationary series.